# Outlook: Order of precedence for search operators?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, search

This [Microsoft Outlook page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da) shows how one can combine search conditions using Boolean operators.

Is there a documented order of precedence for the operators?

I use (1) Outlook 2019 desktop installation for personal stuff and (2) a workplace o365's Outlook web app for work.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by precedence for search operators? Search results will be listed depends on your filter condition.

[image]

Comment: Hi, Aidan, did you visit the page that I linked to? I'm missing the connection with your posted answer.  Each search criterion is either satisified (true) or not satisfied (false).  There is an algebra and order of operations by which these conditions are combined.  See [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-order-of-operations-for-logical-operators) and *Laws of Boolean Algebra* at [Maple](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=MathApps/BooleanAlgebra).  The challenge is that the order of operations depends on the implementation.